# Meaning of ENUM as a data type

Tags: vb.net

I keep reading the statement that 'Enumeration is a datatype'(for example see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/when-to-use-an-enumeration) ). I am trying to understand the meaning of the statement better. So I wrote the following code.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Enum
Module Program
    Enum colours As Byte
        Red = 5
        Blue
        Green
    End Enum
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim c As colours
        Console.WriteLine(c.Red) 'Prints 5
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Because the enum has been declared to be of type BYTE it means that the type of the constants associated with the fields of the enum would be of type byte. But this does not really explain the idea of enum as a data type. So i tried defining a variable of the type `colours` and tried accessing the enumeration members through `Dim c As colours` and `c.Red` and it worked. However two questions comes at this point:

1. `c.Red` gives a warning message `Access of a shared member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated`. I understand the first sentence in the warning message but not the second sentence. What would be the qualifying expression in this case which shall not be evaluated -- `c.Red` works fine??
2. Although I can access enum mmebers through the variable `c`, it seems unnecessary because the same thing can be done by writing `colours.red`. So although the statement `Dim c as colours` makes the enum look more as a data type it does not seem to be of much use. If that is right, can someone pls give me an example which illustrates in a more realistic manner the idea of enum as a data type.

Comment: Get rid of `Imports System.Enum`. That does nothing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `2.` sort of answers your `1.`
You are not supposed to do `c.Red`, you are supposed to do `colours.Red`, and if you do `c.Red` you get the warning.

The qualifying expression that will not be evaluated is `c`.
That is, the compiler will not generate code that accesses the variable `c`. Evaluating a variable is a trivial read-only action that you may even not consider "evaluation", but if you had e.g.

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim c As colours = SomeFunction(AnotherFunction(), YetAnotherFunction()).Red
End Sub


Function SomeFunction(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As String) As colours
    Console.WriteLine("SomeFunction called")
    Return colours.Blue
End Function

Function AnotherFunction() As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("AnotherFunction called")
    Return 42
End Function

Function YetAnotherFunction() As String
    Console.WriteLine("YetAnotherFunction called")
    Return "42"
End Function
```

then the `SomeFunction(AnotherFunction(), YetAnotherFunction())` (this time's "qualifying expression") would be the part is "not evaluated". None of the `SomeFunction`, `AnotherFunction`, `YetAnotherFunction` would be called, and nothing would appear in the console.

---

The purpose of an enum is to guide your fellow programmers in regard of what values are allowed. When you declare `Dim c as colours`, you establish what should and shouldn't be stored in `c`. It is not different from declaring `c As Integer` so that someone could not store `"asd"` in it.

Similarly, `Dim c As colours = 5` would raise a compile-time error, because `5` is an `Integer` rather than a `colours`. So you would be nudged into `Dim c A colours = colours.Red`.

I assume the error does not show for you because you have [`Option Strict Off`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). You should set it to `On`.

Answer (score 1):

The point of an `Enum` is to provide a limited list of valid values in a particular scenario. The underlying type is numeric, so it is very efficient for the system to work with, but the field labels are descriptive and make it very easy for the developer to work with. You could use `String` to make it just as easy for the developer but then you lose the efficiency and you also lose the ability to limit the range of values. Similarly, you could use a numeric data type to retain the efficiency but you then lose the user-friendliness and you also again lose the ability to limit the range of values.

As for using the values, it doesn't make sense to have a field of type `colours` and then access `colours.Red` via that field. That would be like having a field of type `DateTime` and then accessing the `DateTime.TryParse` method via that field. There would be no logic to that. You assign a `DateTime` value to the field, you get a `DateTime` value from the field and you compare that value to other `DateTime` values, but you access the `TryParse` method via the type, not an instance of that type. The same goes for a field on an `Enum` type: you assign a value to it, you get a value from it, you compare that value to other values of the same type but you access the fields of the type via the type itself.

Let's fix your type for a start. Firstly, an `Enum` is a first class type, just like classes, structures and modules. Don't declare an `Enum` inside another type. Like any other type, the only good reason to nest an `Enum` inside another type is if you're going to declare it `Private` and only use it inside the other type. In your case, create a new code file and declare your `Enum` in that. Generally speaking, you should have one type per code file. I tend to break that rule with `Enums` because they are generally very small. For that reason, I have one code file named *Enumerations.vb* and I declare all my `Enums` there.

As for the type itself:

```vb
Enum Colour
    Red = 5
    Blue
    Green
End Enum
```

Like all types, the name should begin with an upper-case letter. There's generally no good reason to specify the numeric type because it will default to `Integer` and that is the most efficient numeric type for the system to deal with. The tiny bit of storage space you save by using `Byte` or `Short` is generally pointless. The name should also be singular except in specific cases that I will cover later. I've left in your initialisation of the `Red` field but generally that's pointless too. Unless the numbers mean something specific beyond the type itself, just accept the defaults.

Generally speaking, a field of an `Enum` type will contain one value. In this case, a `Colour` will be either `Red` or `Blue` or `Green`. There are situations where you may want to store composite values though, e.g. a `Permissions` type where a user can have zero, one or more permissions. In such cases, you should make three changes:

1. The name should be plural rather than singular.
2. The `Flags` attribute should be appliedto the type.
3. The values should be explicitly set to powers of 2.

```vb
<Flags>
Enum Permissions
    Something = 1
    SomethingElse = 2
    YetAnotherThing = 4
End Enum
```

Consumers of the type should be able to tell whether composite values are supported or not by whether the name is plural or singular. Unfortunately, this rule was not always followed for older types. The `Flags` attribute will cause the multiple values to be displayed sensibly when you call `ToString` on a composite value. The powers of 2 mean that each value occupies one and only one bit within a numeric value, so composite values are never ambiguous.

To answer your questions explicitly:

1. The qualifying expression in `c.Red` is `c`. Anything before a dot qualifies what comes after, i.e. there could be a multitude of members named `Red` but the expression before the dot qualifies exactly which one of those is being referred to. In cases like this, `Red` is not a member of a specific instance of `colours` but rather of the `colours` type itself, so the specific instance you use to qualify is ignored and the type is used.
2. Why is the concept of a data type harder to grasp here than anywhere else. You have no trouble understanding why someone would want to store a `String` object in a `String` variable, do you? You have no trouble understanding why someone would want to store an `Integer` value in an `Integer` variable, do you? Why is this any different? Take a look at the `MessageBox.Show` method and the various `Enums` that it takes to control how the message is displayed. In your specific example, let's say that you were representing pixels in a TV that can be red, green or blue. Your `Pixel` class might have a property of type `Colour` and you can then set that property to `Colour.Red`, `Colour.Green` or `Colour.Blue`. It provides information of a specific type, just like any other type.

Comment: many thanks for the detailed write-up, especially the point on the enums having composite values. During my study, I did not know this was possible but now I can study it.